# Google Maps JS API v3 stay at top

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've added a Google Maps JS API to my website with some custom markers. Everything workout great, but when I first load the page, the page scrolls down to the maps, but I would like it to stay at the top.

I've done my research, but I haven't seen anyone else having this problem.

Here is the code and the link for the page.

http://clusier-new.copemanweb.ca/index.php/en/a-propos/contact.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        var map;
        var map2;
        var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

        function initialize() {
          var featureOpts = [
            {
              stylers: [
                { "saturation": -100 },
              ]
            }
          ];
          var styledMapOptions = {
            name: 'Clusier Style'
          };
          var image = 'http://127.0.0.1/clusier-new/media/wysiwyg/marker.png';

          var McGill = new google.maps.LatLng(45.500677,-73.561092);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: McGill,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
            },
            mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('McGill'),
              mapOptions);
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.500417,-73.558087);
          var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              icon: image
          });
          var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);
          map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);

          var Stanley = new google.maps.LatLng(45.500700,-73.578764);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: Stanley,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
            },
            mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
          };
          map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Stanley'),
              mapOptions);
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.500455,-73.575877);
          var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map2,
              icon: image
          });         
          map2.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
// ]]></script>
<div id="visit-us">
<div><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/contact-us-mcgill.jpg"}}" alt="Visit Us McGill" />
<p><span class="DINMedium">Boutique McGill</span><br />432 Rue McGill<br /> Montr&eacute;al, QC<br />H2Y 2G1<br /><br /> <span class="DINMedium">514-842-1717</span></p>
<div id="McGill">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/contact-us-stanley.jpg"}}" alt="Visit Us Stanley" />
<p><span class="DINMedium">Boutique Stanley</span><br />2041 Rue Stanley<br /> Montr&eacute;al, QC<br />H3A 1R7<br /><br /> <span class="DINMedium">514-844-3988</span></p>
<div id="Stanley">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help,

Cope99

Comment: You might have better luck on [Magento's Stack Exchange page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue of the Maps-API, as Andy said it related to  Magento.
The page did not scroll to the map, your contact-form will be focused:

```
var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm',true);
```

set the 2nd argument to false(when it's `true` the form will be focused).